# Razor Page page model file without corresponding content file

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm using Razor Pages. Sometimes I need a page model file without the corresponding content file. But I must nonetheless specify a route for that page, and so define a content file anyway, just for the `@page "/foo"`.

Example: the user clicks a link in a confirmation email, which leads to a token confirmation callback page `/confirm`. That redirects to various other pages based on whether the token was valid; e.g. `/login`, `/resend-token`, `/error`. So the page itself never renders content.

`Confirm.cshtml`

```cs
@page "/confirm"
@model ConfirmModel
@{ throw new InvalidOperationException("This page should never be rendered."); }
```

`Confirm.cshtml.cs`

```cs
public class ConfirmModel : PageModel
{
  public IActionResult OnGet()
  {
    // handles various scenarios; each redirects somewhere else
    // never returns `Page()`
    // ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid that useless `Confirm.cshtml` content file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need endpoints in a Razor Pages app that have no corresponding UI, you can use a standard MVC controller or a minimal API request handler (https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/358/using-minimal-apis-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages)

For example, in your Program.cs file, you would add this:

```
app.MapGet("/confirm", async (HttpContext context, [FromServices]IMyService service ) => {
    await service.PerformSomeTaskAsync();
    context.Response.Redirect("/some-url");
});
```

Comment: I didn't realise how easy it is to mix RP, MVC and Minimal APIs in the the same project... It'll make low-ceremony ajax/fetch so easy. Many thanks!

Comment: Been experimenting... For simplicity, I found for only a few such pages, the approach I showed is inelegant but "good enough" (with the failsafe of throwing an exception from the content page). That also ensures collocation of related items and is less surprising to other team members. But once there are numerous cases, your approach is significantly better; also it would be prudent to move those handlers elsewhere to avoid adding complexity to Program.cs. I plan to do that once I add ajax/fetch endpoints to my app. Once again, outstanding answer, and very helpful blog post - thanks.

Comment: @Ionix I'll add  e.g. a _ProductEndpoints.cs_ file to the _Pages/Products_ folder and create an extension  on `IEndpointRouteBuilder` called `MapProductEndpoints` within which all my request handlers for that entity are declared. Then call `app.MapProductEndpoints()` in _Program.cs_

Comment: I experimented with the Minimal APIs option but realised - in my particular use case - that I was recreating MVC/WebAPI. So I decided on WebAPI, as it's very similar to RazorPages. Added my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MikeBrind's answer which explains that one can mix Razor Pages, MVC, WebAPI and Minimal APIs in the same project.

I opted for WebAPI as it's the simplest solution to my particular problem.

Update `Program.cs`:

```cs
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddMvcCore();    // <--- (not strictly necessary, included by AddRazorPages)
// ...
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();     // <---
```

Then add controllers, which can be located anywhere, not just in `MyProject/Controllers/`. To keep it simple, they can be placed alongside the RazorPages assets in `MyProject/Pages/`.

From my example above, convert this RazorPage duo `/Pages/Confirm.cshtml.cs` and `/Pages/Confirm.cshtml`:

```cs
public class ConfirmModel : PageModel
{
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() { /* ... */ }
}
```

```cs
@page "/confirm"
@model ConfirmModel
```

...to this WebAPI controller `/Pages/Confirm.cs`:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ConfirmController : ControllerBase {

  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Post() { /* ... */ }

}
```

The nice thing about the WebAPI option is that controllers/actions are very similar to RazorPages in behaviour and have similar method signatures, which aids in "readability" and thus maintenance.

This approach also makes it really easy to add REST endpoints to the app (via ajax/fetch).

Comment: One proviso: it's common to use `TempData` in RazorPages. If you need it in that controller then you must use MVC rather than WebAPI. So change `AddMvcCore()` to `AddControllersWithViews()`, `[ApiController]` to `[Controller]`, and  `ControllerBase` to `Controller`.